# MySQL Workbench incompatible/nonstandard server

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am new to using MySQL and I needed to download it for school, however, I keep getting this error message (picture below). I am using xampp and connecting using the username root. the port also matches what it is telling me. It will let me proceed but a lot of the features are missing. Any help at all would be appreciated.

> Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol
>   detected (10.0.10).
>
> A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL
>   Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not
>   fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
>
> MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.1,
>   5.5, 5.6 and 5.7

[image: PICTURE HERE]

Comment: And what version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 53):

As I can see, You are using latest XAMPP.

All you need to do is, after opening **MySQL Workbench**, and instead of setting up a new connection, Press **CTRL+R** or click on **DATABASE tab in the top menu**. Select **Reverse Engineer** and provide necessary information. You are good to go now.

The MySql workbench wont crash or show any compatibility issue now.

Comment: I did it but still have the same message
Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.3.12).

A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.

MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.1, 5.5, 5.6 and 5.7

Comment: which web server uses mysql then. I am on ubuntu

Comment: This lets me see the database, but it doesn't let me do much with it. In particular I didn't find a way to import data from a .csv file I saved from another database. It works indeed, but it doesn't seem so useful to me.

Answer (score 18):

The current version of XAMPP uses MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Because MySQL Workbench is [designed to work with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927871/mysql-workbench-6-3-5-crashes-when-opening-xampp-mysql-local-database) and not with the very similar drop in replacement MariaDB, you are gonna have problems ...

So, if you want to use MySQL Workbench with XAMPP then a solution would be to try installing the *last* version of XAMPP that uses MySQL. That version is probably [1.8.3](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/) from (August of 2014?).  You can download it here:

[XAMPP Sourceforge old versions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/)

Comment: when you say "you are gonna have problems", do you have a source? According to another (more complete) stack exchange answer, "In most cases, it can be safely ignored." http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252275/mysql-workbench-warning-when-connecting-to-mariadb

Comment: Well Patrick, I suppose I could have been slightly more precise and said "you may have problems", but I was linking to an Oracle Team Leader comment:

"Ah right, MySQL Workbench really only supports MySQL. In the next version this will be shown more prominently. – Mike Lischke Nov 27 '15 at 8:13"

I was also coming off having to troubleshoot why I couldn't connect, so personal experience too.  The problem I ran into wasn't that I could connect and then there where edge cases where it didn't work, it was that I couldn't connect at all.

Comment: @Patrick - My xampp installation has mysql and I still get this error. The mysql windows installer does not let me install another mysql. How do i make this work ?

Comment: This is the same thing as saying you shouldn't use LibreOffice to edit MS Word docs. If the tool is compatible 99% of the time then it shouldn't care about branding.

Comment: I have ran into a problem using workbench with MariaDB which you can check out [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160181/error-code-1064-in-workbench-8-0-from-forward-engineered-eerd)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the latest XAMPP that uses MariaDB, in that case in your MySQL Workbench don't use 'Connect to Database' instead use 'Reverse Engineer' and provide the necessary credentials. That's all, No hassle.

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same message **followed by a crash of MySQL Workbench**, with version 6.3.7 (build 1199).

I didn't find a solution, but here is a work-around:

Once you press the button `Continue anyway`, just open a database `use toto`, and then wait a bit (a minute is enough in my case), and then you can call a query without a crash. I found this trick [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76909).

Comment: please mention the workaround instead of posting the link. your answer will not be useful once the link is dead.

Comment: Do you read the answer ? that's what I did. I mention the workarround before giving the link !

Answer (score 1):

I experimented the same with WAMP 3.2.0.

MariaDB was configured to listen to port 3306 (the usal MySQL port) and MySQL 8 was listening on port 3308. If you are in this case, don't be fooled by the fact you have 2 DBs.

To solve this, you have to choose the DB you want. I wanted MySQL and I just ask MySQLWorkBench to open a connection on port 3308 to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can ditch MySQL Workbench, and use the browser made for the MariaDB, they have a free version here: https://www.upscene.com/downloads/dbw

It's limited in its abilities, but I had no troubles connecting and browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem because i was using **Denwer** at the same time.
To solve the problem:

1. Stop Denwer
2. Restart MySQL server
3. Profit! Now you can open your database in the Workbench

The idea is that denwer was starting its local server which didnt allow MySQL to start normally.

If you want to use denwer at the same time wth MySQL you can just start it after MySQL (Point 4).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I already had MySql server and workbench installed and setup prior to my XAMPP installation. I wanted to continue with my existing setup.

I also installed MySql server with my XAMPP. I started mysql inside XAMPP and when I connected to MySql Workbench, I encountered the same error. Because Workbench was trying to connect with the server which was installed with XAMPP, apparently this was incompatible.

So I stopped mysql in XAMPP and started started mysql server manually(the previous setup and installed server).

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509148/how-to-start-mysql-server-on-windows-xp#:%7E:text=To%20start%20the%20mysqld%20server,of%20MySQL%20on%20your%20system) to know how to start mysql manually in windows.

You can also [config XAMPP to use your existing SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394509/installing-and-integrating-xampp-with-an-existing-mysql-server).

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem. For me none of the methods worked, but then I found out that my MariaDB was occupying the same port, so I uninstalled it and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue, i changed the mysql server port from 3306 to 3308 in XAMPP config file.

[mysqld]
port=3308

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a version mismatch between Workbench and Server.

You can downgrade Server to version [8.0.36](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), and it will be working fine with workbench version [8.0.36](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35643721)