# Installing and integrating xampp with an existing MySQL server

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a working installation of MySQL Server in my windows development machine which I use when working with Java. However, I want to install xampp without the database server it comes with. How do I make other Xampp Apps like phpmyadmin recognize my working MySQL Server instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've resolve this problem.

click XAMPP---Apache's <kbd>config</kbd> button,and click PhpAdmin will show the phpMyAdmin's directory quickly, and edit "config.inc.php" and modify the user and password,the defualt port is 3306 ,then restart Apache server.

Comment: This is the way. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've done this in the past when I had an older Xampp application, but a newer MySQL on my PC (separate from Xampp). You can still install Xampp with MySQL, just don't install/start the MySQL service in Xampp.

So, the phpMyAdmin "should" still connect to the local (non-Xampp) MySQL instance, assuming standard port config 3306, otherwise you might have to 'tweak' the phpMyAdmin config.