# Error Code 1064 in Workbench 8.0 from forward engineered EERD

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

I get the following error from my forward engineered database:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1`     FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeTitle_EmpT' at line 9

The code looks good to me and I have no idea where to go from here to make it work. The code is as follows:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema A2Lewis
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema A2Lewis
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `A2Lewis` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`EmployeeTitle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`EmployeeTitle` (
  `EmpTitleID` INT NOT NULL,
  `EmpTitle` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmpTitleID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO EmployeeTitle VALUES
(01, "Sales Representative"),
(02, "Tour Guide");
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Employees`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Employees` (
  `empID` INT NOT NULL,
  `empFirst` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empLast` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empWage` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `empPhone` CHAR(10) NULL,
  `EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empID`),
  INDEX `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1_idx` (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`EmployeeTitle` (`EmpTitleID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES
(01, "Thomas", "Lewis", 12.00, 6134493075, 01),
(02, "John", "Doe", 11.25, 6135554267, 01),
(03, "Sarah", "Simon", 11.00, 6135554582, 01), 
(04, "Connor", "Toth", 15.00, 6135557894, 02),
(05, "James", "Young", 13.50, 6135554528, 02),
(06, "Ben", "Zimmer", 14.75, 6135554287, 02);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Tours`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Tours` (
  `tourID` INT NOT NULL,
  `tourName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tourMeetLoc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tourDist` INT NULL,
  `tourMaxCust` INT NULL,
  `tourCost` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
  `tourProvince` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tourDate` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tourID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Tours VALUES
(01, "Sightseeing tour of Halifax", "City of Halifax", 15, 35, 585.00, "Nova Scotia", 2019-03-05),
(02, "The Sun and Sand Trail", "City of Bathurst", 250, 20, 999.99, "New Brunswick", 2019-07-10),
(03, "Quebec Countryside Tour", "Chemin du Roy", 89, 30, 800.00, "Quebec", 2019-10-15);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Seasons`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Seasons` (
  `seasID` INT NOT NULL,
  `seasName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`seasID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Seasons VALUES
(01, "Early Spring"),
(02, "Mid Spring"),
(03, "Late Spring"),
(04, "Early Summer"),
(05, "Mid Summer"),
(06, "Late Summer"),
(07, "Early Fall"),
(08, "Mid Fall"),
(09, "Late Fall");
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Equipment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Equipment` (
  `equipID` INT NOT NULL,
  `equipDescr` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `equipPrice` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `Tours_tourID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`equipID`),
  INDEX `fk_Equipment_Tours1_idx` (`Tours_tourID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Equipment_Tours1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Tours_tourID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Tours` (`tourID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES
(01, "Four Person Tent", 89.00, 02),
(02, "Adult Bicycle", 50.00, 03);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Customers` (
  `custID` INT NOT NULL,
  `custFirst` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `custLast` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cust65` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `custStud` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`custID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES
(01, "Thomas", "O'Neill", 0, 0),
(02, "Melissa", "Kennedy", 0, 1),
(03, "Craig", "Smith", 0, 0);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Reservation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Reservation` (
  `reservID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Tours_tourID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Employees_empID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Customers_custID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservID`, `Employees_empID`),
  INDEX `fk_Booking_Tours1_idx` (`Tours_tourID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Booking_Employees1_idx` (`Employees_empID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Reservation_Customers1_idx` (`Customers_custID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Booking_Tours1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Tours_tourID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Tours` (`tourID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Booking_Employees1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Employees_empID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Employees` (`empID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reservation_Customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Customers_custID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Customers` (`custID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Reservation VALUES
(01, 01, 04, 01),
(02, 02, 05, 02),
(03, 03, 06, 03);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `A2Lewis`.`Tours_has_Seasons`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Tours_has_Seasons` (
  `Tours_tourID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Seasons_seasID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Tours_tourID`, `Seasons_seasID`),
  INDEX `fk_Tours_has_Seasons_Seasons1_idx` (`Seasons_seasID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Tours_has_Seasons_Tours1_idx` (`Tours_tourID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tours_has_Seasons_Tours1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Tours_tourID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Tours` (`tourID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tours_has_Seasons_Seasons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Seasons_seasID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`Seasons` (`seasID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Tours_has_Seasons VALUES
(01,01),
(02,05),
(03,07);

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Looks good to me. What specific version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: That error is usually related to unbalanced parenthesis. But they look balanced to me. Are you sure this is the exact code that is producing the error?

Comment: Literally copy and pasted the code out of my script. How do I check the server version?

Comment: It's the `INDEX` line. If you comment it out, it works. Let me check the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because of incompatibility between MySQL and MariaDB.

This script is apparently for MySQL, but it's run on MariaDB. Even though MariaDB was originally 100% compatible with MySQL both databases have now diverged. Many people consider MariaDB more advanced now, but that fact is they now have small/big differences here and there.

In this case, when creating an index, the keyword `VISIBLE` is not supported by MariaDB. Instead of using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Employees` (
  `empID` INT NOT NULL,
  `empFirst` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empLast` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empWage` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `empPhone` CHAR(10) NULL,
  `EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empID`),
  INDEX `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1_idx` (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`EmployeeTitle` (`EmpTitleID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A2Lewis`.`Employees` (
  `empID` INT NOT NULL,
  `empFirst` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empLast` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empWage` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `empPhone` CHAR(10) NULL,
  `EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empID`),
  INDEX `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1_idx` (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Employees_EmployeeTitle1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeTitle_EmpTitleID`)
    REFERENCES `A2Lewis`.`EmployeeTitle` (`EmpTitleID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The second query (for MariaDB) does not require `VISIBLE` since indexes are visible by default in MariaDB.