# Installed XAMPP Version 8.1.5-0 in mac(m1 pro) to run a php file from htdocs but it is now giving me error when I open MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

[image: MYSQL Workbench Error image]Error says:

> Connection warning(Local Instance 3306)
>
> Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol
> detected (10.4.21).
>
> A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL
> Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not
> fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
>
> MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.6,
> 5.7 and 8.0. For MySQL Server older than 5.6, please use MySQL Workbench version 6.3.

Note: Previously I was not using XAMPP. I was running MySQL Workbench on default apache server of mac which was preinstalled.

I was trying to run a .php file, but it doesn't let me open MySQL Workbench anymore.

If I do, "Continue Anyways". The table doesn't load, and the connection doesn't establish.

Comment: Which version of mySQL workbench is this?

Comment: See the following answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380655/5389997 Please do bear in mind in the future that mariadb is **NOT** mysql!