# mysql 5.7.18 failed to start on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I did look up the web for a solution such as this [very relevant post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509148/how-to-start-mysql-server-on-windows-xp), to no avail.

Here is the steps that I installed mysql for win 10 and attempts to start it:

1. downloaded mysql 5.7.18 zip file and unzip it into my app folder;
2. open "cmd" as admin and run "**mysqld --install**", it shows "Service successfully installed."
3. run "**net start mysql**", it shows:

```
    The MySQL service is starting.
    The MySQL service could not be started.
    The service did not report an error.
    More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

4. Run "**mysqld.exe --console**", it chunked out lines of messages like below:

```
    2017-07-16T14:55:49.066437Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2017-07-16T14:55:49.077216Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
    2017-07-16T14:55:49.081191Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 15872 ...
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.167310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.167310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.168434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.169398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.195084Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.249204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.290217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.296068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.453825Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.813667Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2017-07-16T14:55:50.815630Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.040444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.062121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.062590Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.068603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.128491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 1210018
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.132269Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Users\jonat\opt\mysql-5.7.18-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.133249Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.165071Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.233060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170716 10:55:51
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.251567Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.267669Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.272001Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.274922Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.278873Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.281791Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.308759Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

    2017-07-16T14:55:51.310583Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.311554Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

    2017-07-16T14:55:51.312531Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.314481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.314481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.314481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.315463Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.315463Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.316444Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
    2017-07-16T14:55:51.319389Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
    ....
    2017-07-16T14:55:52.615409Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
    2017-07-16T14:55:52.618322Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Please do everything that is listed in the second answer in your linked question. You very likely didn't do a `mysqld --initialize-insecure` (or `mysqld --initialize`).

Comment: great! that works! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL installation root folder (suppose it is c:\mysql), create a text file, say mypass.txt and copy this line to it:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<yourpassword>';
```

The run

```
mysqld --initialize
mysqld --init-file=c:/mysql/mypass.txt
```

And if you want to run MySQL as a Windows Service:

```
mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="c:/mysql/my.ini"
```